# VBScript Create puzzle by splitting document into multiple documents that cannot be read separately

Tags: vbscript, char

For a scavenger hunt I wanted to give my nephews 4 parts of the same letter that they would have to combine to read. I couldn't find anything online to use quickly, so I wrote one. I will updated with better code if you have some ideas.

```
'******************  Change things here ****************

'Change the number in perenthesis to set the number of files
Dim Letters(4)

'Set the original filename here:
originalFile = "Letter.txt"

'Set a letter to use as a syncronizer in addition to punctuation and line breaks
charSync = asc("o")

'*********************************************************

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(originalFile , 1)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strCharacters = objFile.Read(1)

Randomize
selLetter = Int((Ubound(Letters))*Rnd+1)

If (asc(strCharacters) < 46) or (asc(strCharacters) = charSync) then
    for i = 1 to Ubound(Letters)
         Letters(i) = Letters(i) & strCharacters
    next 
else
    for i = 1 to Ubound(Letters)
        if i = selLetter then
            Letters(i) = Letters(i) & strCharacters
        else
            Letters(i) = Letters(i) & " "
        end if
    next 
end if
Loop

For n = 1 to Ubound(Letters)
outFileName = replace(originalFile ,".",n & ".")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFileName,True)
    objFile.Write Letters(n)
    objFile.Close
next

Set objFSO=Nothing
```

Usage:

1. Create a text file you want to split up randomly
2. Edit the script for the following:
3. Set the number of documents to split it into
4. Set the file name of the file to update
5. Select a synch character if you want to
6. Run the script and it will create numbered files
7. Use equal character spacing font like system to read by holding up to light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'******************  Change things here ****************

'Change the number in perenthesis to set the number of files
Dim Letters(4)

'Set the original filename here:
originalFile = "Letter.txt"

'Set a letter to use as a syncronizer in addition to punctuation and line breaks
charSync = asc("o")

'*********************************************************

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(originalFile , 1)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strCharacters = objFile.Read(1)
'uncomment next 2 comments to simplify and change only once per word:
'If strCharacters = " " then
    Randomize
    selLetter = Int((Ubound(Letters))*Rnd+1)
'end if

If (asc(strCharacters) < 46) or (asc(strCharacters) = charSync) then
    for i = 1 to Ubound(Letters)
         Letters(i) = Letters(i) & strCharacters
    next 
else
    for i = 1 to Ubound(Letters)
        if i = selLetter then
            Letters(i) = Letters(i) & strCharacters
        else
            Letters(i) = Letters(i) & " "
        end if
    next 
end if
Loop

For n = 1 to Ubound(Letters)
outFileName = replace(originalFile ,".",n & ".")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFileName,True)
    objFile.Write Letters(n)
    objFile.Close
next

Set objFSO=Nothing
```

Usage:

1. Create a text file you want to split up randomly
2. Edit the script for the following:
3. Set the number of documents to split it into
4. Set the file name of the file to update
5. Select a synch character if you want to
6. Run the script and it will create numbered files
7. Use equal character spacing font like system to read by holding up to light